# in_array not finding an element

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using a PDO approach to get an array out of database:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT sname FROM list WHERE ongoing = 1;");
$statement->execute();
$snames = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
var_dump($snames);
```

The dump output is (total 2500 results):

> [69]=> string(13) "ah-my-goddess"
>
> **[70]=> string(17) "ahiru-no-oujisama"**
>
> [71]=> string(13) "ahiru-no-sora"

Then I check if array `$snames` contains the new element `$sname`:

```
$sname = current(explode(".", $href_word_array[count($href_word_array)-1]));
if (in_array($sname, $snames) == False)
{
    echo "New '$sname'!<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "$sname is already in the list. Excluding.<br>";
    unset($snames[$sname]);
}
```

And the output is:

> 'ah-my-goddess' is already in the list. Excluding.
>
> **New 'ahiru-no-oujisama'!**
>
> 'ahiru-no-sora' is already in the list. Excluding.

Why does it says that 'ahiru-no-oujisama' is the new name? We can see from the DUMP function that the array contains this element.

I have compared the results a thousand times. Notepad finds both names. There are no spaces. Name in the database is the same as in variable..

For the record - I have around 2500 entities in `$snames` array and for 95% of records (+-) I am getting the "already exists" result. However, for some I am getting "new".

Is that perhaps some kind of encoding issue? For the table I have  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1. Could that be a problem?

### Edit

It was suggested that I added a trim operation:

```
$snames = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
for ($i=0; $i < Count($snames); $i+=1)
{
    $snames[$i] = trim($snames[$i]);
}
```

and:

```
if (in_array(trim($sname), $snames) == False)
```

However I get the same problem.

Comment: i suggest to trim both...and try again

Comment: You're seeking an array value that matches, correct? And not an array key that matches? You seem to be using $sname as an array key if it exists, maybe you mean to use array_key_exists()?

Comment: @JasonOOO used trim on all items in array and on the new name. Still not able to find an element. See edit.

Comment: can you provide real data in a text file? but should be exactly same copy that you are working on them

Comment: To debbug, try to test $snames[70] == $name

Comment: @doydoy44 - I get it now!!! Your post made me thinking about the number 70 and I rememberd where I have see it before! In the database I have entries with names: sname = "70", sname  = "111", and some others. Search fails for elements with such indexes (not names)! Have to analyze it a little bit to come up with the solution...

Comment: by the way: $snames[70] outputs "ahiru-no-oujisama".. SOLVED! Edit will come next

Comment: @doydoy44 problem fixed. See the solution in the post below ;) Everybody thank you for the help! esp doydoy

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem was with line:

```
unset($snames[$sname]);
```

for some entries I had names such as "70" and "111"

as the result command:

```
unset($snames[$sname]);
```

removed elements at that position. Not the elements with such keys!! I.e. That's how program understood it:

```
unset($snames[77]);
```

and that's what I was expecting:

```
unset($snames['77']);
```

so the line had to be changed to following:

```
if(($key = array_search($sname, $snames)) !== false)
{
    unset($snames[$key]);
}
```